# Cookie Authentication for Client - is session store needed?

Tags: express

I am creating an application and I am looking for a solution for user authentication (checking if the user is logged in, basically). I am reading online and it seems that many people recommend using a session store/table in your db (store roles, views etc..) vs. just storing the cookie id in the DB in that users column. My question is, what is the difference between storing this data in a "session" store, which is basically just another table and storing this data in your database alongside the other user data (username, passwordHash etc..). I understand that this is useful for data that may change when the user logs in and out again, but are there any advantages to having a session store if my applications state stays consistent across log ins. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to store user data between HTTP requests and sessions helps you to do so.When a user visits our site, it creates a new session for the user and assigns them a cookie. Next time the user comes to the site , the cookie is checked and the session id which is stored in the cookie is retrieved and searched in the session store .Session store is a place where you store all your data regarding your session.So using a session store automates this method and it eases your work.So whenever someone pings your server it will add the session id of the user in your database. I will recommend foe you to look into JWT which is also a interesting way to do authentication.